# Cannot update Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: updates, update-manager, 9.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

I am using Ubuntu 9.04 and having problem updating. When I start the Update Manager, I get a message saying:

> Could not download all repository indexes
>
> The repository may no longer be available or could not be contacted because of network problems. If available an older version of the failed index will be used. Otherwise the repository will be ignored. Check your network connection and ensure the repository address in the preferences is correct.

Then I close it and click Upgrade, and I get this error:

> Could not find the release notes.
>
> The server may be overloaded.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

9.04 is not supported anymore, it has reached its end of life in Oct 2010.

You can still update it to the latest packages released by that time (no new packages or bug fixes were released for 9.04 after Oct 2010, beware of that, these where the last updated packages and that is all you will get).

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` with your favorite text editor, ie:

> sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

Add these 3 lines to the end of the file or modify the current lines to reflect the *old-releases* necessary sub domain

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Optional is the backports repository, you can add it or not after those 3 lines

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

After this is done and the file has been saved you can update your system to those package's versions with `sudo apt-get update`, and has an option you can also upgrade to a newer version if desired.